# drawRect: in custom NSView ignores its own instance variables

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, class

I have a custom NSView class named "testClass." I create an instance of this class in my main application controller class. testClass contains a 4 element float array as an instance variable that holds colors for the NSView's background. I want to set those values from the main controller class, and then drawRect: should use them to draw the background. However, when I set the values, drawRect refuses to see them. They're always 0.0.

In Interface Builder, I put the custom view in the main window of the app's MainMenu.xib. I then assign it to testClass.

Here's my code:

```
@interface testClass : NSView
{
    @public
    float colors[4];
}
@end

@implementation testClass
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    //The colors are ALWAYS 0.0, 0.0, 0.0:
    fprintf(stderr,"colors: %.2f %.2f %.2f\n",colors[0],colors[1],colors[2]);

    NSColor *c = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:colors[0] green:colors[1] blue:colors[2] alpha:1.0];
    [c setFill];

    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
@end

//Now, in the main app controller:
testClass *test = [[testClass alloc] init];
test->colors[0] = 1.00; //r
test->colors[1] = 0.75; //g
test->colors[2] = 0.25; //b
test->colors[3] = 1.00; //a

[test setNeedsDisplay:YES];

//This prints the colors as they should be:
fprintf(stderr,"colors: %.2f %.2f %.2f\n",
    test->colors[0],
    test->colors[1],
    test->colors[2]);
```

Why does the custom view not recognize its own variables, even if I call setNeedsDisplay:YES from the class that created the custom class? If what I'm trying to do won't work, then what's the correct approach?

**Update:**

As user1118321 pointed out, the instance of testClass I created with the [[testClass alloc] init] line wasn't what I should have done. Since I already had an instance of testClass in the form of a Custom View in Interface Builder (to which I assigned "testClass"), I just needed to create a pointer to it as an IBOutlet in the main controller class. Once I did that, it worked!

Comment: I have a Custom View placed in the window in Interface Builder. I then assign it to "testClass" (I updated the question with this info).

Comment: Well, you were right. I was mistakenly creating a new instance of testClass that had nothing to do with the Custom View in Interface Builder. That's why it wasn't updating. I instead created a pointer to testClass inside my main app controller class as an IBOutlet and linked that to the custom view in IB. It now works!